# printer get printed in the server in stead of client

Tags: java, printing

I have a java program which prints raw data to thermal printer. The code works perfect in server but when accessed in client it prints on the server's printer itself instead of client's default printer.
Below is the code i used to print.Please help me with the code.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintException;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;

import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies;

import javax.print.event.PrintJobAdapter;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobEvent;

public class PrintText {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws PrintException, IOException {

        String defaultPrinter = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService().getName();
        System.out.println("Default printer: " + defaultPrinter);
        PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

        // prints the famous hello world! plus a form feed
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream("\nMadha Enterprice\n".getBytes(UTF8));

        PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        pras.add(new Copies(1));

        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);
        DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

        PrintJobWatcher pjw = new PrintJobWatcher(job);
        job.print(doc, pras);
        pjw.waitForDone();
        is.close();
    }
}

class PrintJobWatcher {
    boolean done = false;

    PrintJobWatcher(DocPrintJob job) {
        job.addPrintJobListener(new PrintJobAdapter() {
            public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
                allDone();
            }

            public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
                allDone();
            }

            public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
                allDone();
            }

            public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
                allDone();
            }

            void allDone() {
                synchronized (PrintJobWatcher.this) {
                    done = true;
                    System.out.println("Printing done ...");
                    PrintJobWatcher.this.notify();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public synchronized void waitForDone() {
        try {
            while (!done) {
                wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean server? I don't see any client / server architecture here ... Is this code running on server and is a part of a web app, or are you running the exact code you have posted on 'client' ?

Comment: This is not the exact program but its the exact logic I have used. I am using jersey rest api with same logic to print to the client machine. server is Tomcat7.

Comment: If this code is executed at server side - it will print at server side. It is as simple as that. You are not making it clear how exactly this code is invoked... so it is not clear where the execution is performed. However from your problem description I would deduce that it is executed at server side...

Comment: When the client requests the print service the above code has to print raw data to the client's default printer.

Answer (score 1):

With the following code:

```
PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
```

You select the default printer on the machine this code runs - if this runs on the server, then it is expected that it prints on the servers default printer.